# 406 err while data returning from spring java controller to angularjs service

Tags: javascript, angularjs, spring-mvc, http-status-code-406

am stuck at geting data from controller to angular service please check my code any body suggest me what to do

thanks in advance

pom.xml

```
  <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-annotations -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.4</version>
        </dependency>
```

java controller

```
@RequestMapping(value="/getAlluserDetails", method=RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public List<Map<String, Object>> getAllUserDetails(){
    System.out.println("getAllUserDetails");
    ModelMap mav =new ModelMap();
    List<Map<String, Object>> listofusers = userServices.getUserData();
    System.out.println("listofusers : "+listofusers);
    return listofusers;
```

index.html

```js
app.service("myServices",function($q,$http,$log) {
 var deffered = $q.defer();
 var responseData;
 this.getUsers = function(){
  return $http({
   method:'GET',
   url:'getAlluserDetails.htm'
//   data: JSON.stringify(search)
  }).then(function(response){
//   $scope.users = response.data;
   $log.info("samei"+response);
   return response;
  },function(reason){
   $log.info("samei 123err"+reason);
   return reason;
  });

 };
```

```html
 <!doctype html>
<html ng-app="app">
<head lang="en">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>AngularJS Routing</title>
<script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.13/angular.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.2.8/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="resources/scripts/main.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="resources/static/services/services.js"></script>
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.1/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/static/css/style.css">
 <script type="text/javascript" src="resources/static/controllers/LoginController.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="resources/static/controllers/UserController.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="resources/static/controllers/GetUserDetailsController.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container" width="100px">
      <h2>Medhassu user data upload</h2>
      <div ui-view></div>
 </div>
```

in my browser

> response header

Content-Language
en
Content-Length
1067
Content-Type
text/html;charset=utf-8
Date
Sun, 25 Feb 2018 15:49:04 GMT
Server
Apache-Coyote/1.1

> request header

Accept
application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding 
gzip, deflate
Accept-Language 
en-US,en;q=0.5
Connection
keep-alive
Host
localhost:8081
Referer 
http://localhost:8081/UserRegistration/
User-Agent
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; W…) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/58.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

None of the converters or dependencies helped from 406 status i have just converted to Gson in my spring controller before my data is returning to angularjs service (which should be done by Spring instead of me).This is what i have did

if any one have better solution then this, please let me know

Answer (score 0):

HTTP 406 indicates that the response provided is not acceptable by the target.

For returning a ModelAndView use `Content-Type = text/html`

If it is an object(list,map..)/JSON use `Content-Type = application/json` and change the request url to `http://<context>/getAlluserDetails`

Comment: Thanks for reply....I have tried content type= app/JSON at angularjs service but no use can u pls be more specific where to use contenttype and I want to return only list not view so I don't want use modlandview.     You said URL I don't get it